# Capturing all messages that are directed to console in linux

Tags: linux, logging, console

Is there a way how we can capture all the console messages to a file that are coming from different applications in linux.

Comment: Define 'different applications'. Shell is an application, do you want to capture command prompt too?

Comment: I am working on a embedded linux device and will have applications like multimedia, network or user apps that will keep printing their logs on to console and I want to redirect or have copy of all the logs that come on to console into a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in /etc/syslog.conf or /etc/rsyslog.conf add something like below

usually syslog or rsyslog.

```
*.*                                    -/var/log/allmessages
```

more advanced options available

```
# => all acpid messages for debuging (uncomment if needed):
if     ($programname == 'acpid' or $syslogtag == '[acpid]:') then \
       -/var/log/acpid
```

Using rsyslog you can even log to mysql database.

This can be dangerous as you can fill your hard drive/storage and crash your OS if you don't delete them at some point.

Comment: I already tried with syslog.conf change but it did not work for me. Might be due to busy box version of syslogd do not have that support. Also I tried with below which did not work,                                                                                                               # Log all writes to /dev/console to a separate file.
     console.*           /var/log/console.log

Comment: @Reddy Did you add your rule at the very top of the syslog.conf or the bottom?  If you added to the end no messages will reach that point.

Comment: I have added it at the top of file.                                                        kern.debug       /logs/kernel.log                    
*.*              /logs/sys.log                                                                                               But its not working. I did not see any kernel.log but I can see logs in sys.log which will only contain logs from different modules but nothing from kernel or console.

Comment: using rsyslogd instead syslogd solved the problem for me. Due to some reason syslogd was not working as per the rules defined.